# How can I find out what version of SQL Server supports the sp_refreshsqlmodule sproc?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a customer with SQL Server 2005 RTM version installed which does not have the sp_refreshsqlmodule sproc.

How can I find out what minimum version of SQL Server supports this sproc? Or more generally, how do I find out what system sprocs are contained in what versions of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sean pointed out [SQL Server 2005 supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) it but you'll notice the note at the top

> New: 12 December 2006

If you cross reference it [with the SQL Teams SQL Server Version list](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-versions)

```
9.00.3042.01    SQL Server 2005 "SP2a"  5 Mar 2007
9.00.3042       SQL Server 2005 SP2     1 Feb 2007
9.00.2047       SQL Server 2005 SP1 
9.00.1399       SQL Server 2005 RTM     1 Nov 2005
```

it probably didn't exist until SP2

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation SQL Server 2005 supports it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754(v=SQL.90).aspx

SQL Server 2005 sprocs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176007(v=SQL.90).aspx

SQL Server 2008 sprocs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176007(v=SQL.100).aspx

SQL Server 2008 R2 sprocs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176007(v=SQL.105).aspx